# Metadata in the windows file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, metadata

Windows file explorer can show metadata for certain image or movie files, but not documents (pdf, epub) or executables. I have to use external tools like [Metadata++](https://logipole.com/metadata++-en.htm). Is there a way to integrate a metadata option in the file explorer context menu? I tried [file meta](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta/releases), which shows metadata in the details tab, but it cannot read metadata by default, only what this application saves.